# How to implement here hiding and displaying items in the list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I found a code that outputs a multi-level list into Angular here
http://jsfiddle.net/c4Kp8/

```js
var items = [{
 title: 'Something',
 children: [
  { title: 'Hello World' },
  { title: 'Hello Overflow' },
  { title: 'John Doe', children: [
   { title: 'Amazing title' },
   { title: 'Google it' },
   { title: 'Im a child', children: [
    { title: 'Another ' },
    { title: 'He\'s my brother' },
    { title: 'She\'s my mother.', children: [
     {title: 'You never know if im going to have children'}
    ]}
   ]}
  ]}
 ]
}];

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function( $scope ) {
    $scope.items = items;
});


app.directive('nestedItem', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element){
        console.log(element);
            if (scope.item.children){
                var html = $compile('<ul><li nested-item ng-repeat="item in item.children">{{item.title}}</li></ul>')(scope);
                element.append(html);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
   <ul>
       <li nested-item ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.title}}</li>
   </ul>         
</div>
```

How to implement here hiding and displaying items in the list? Only Angular not jquery....

Comment: Can you explain behavior? Do you want to toggle entire list or parts of it?

Comment: Please describe more about your requirement. Hiding and displaying items is fine. But how? Is there will be a button for each item? Or a Single button? If there is a button on each item then do you want to hide the sub element also with that item?

Comment: I want to open a branch. As the tree. Opens first, then the user opens the second and so on. I just have a bad English :)

Comment: Like here: https://www.jstree.com/demo/

Comment: It will be a list of organizations.It is seen only the first, then turn on the drop-down list

Answer (score 1):

Hope you know that, you can make nested ng-repeat without special directive for it :-) ?

You can use for example angular-ui.bootstrap.collapse, or some custom solutions.

```
Solutions:
```

[Angular UI Bootrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse)

[Googled custom solution](http://codepen.io/mickeyvip/pen/Blfns)

Comment: I would not like to use additional libraries just for this feature

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-show / ng-hide / ng-if

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: I read but can not figure out how to check that the upper element is opened.

Comment: Add a variable in the object that holds a boolean for "IsOpened".

Comment: var items = [{title: "foo", isOpened: false, children: [{title: "bar", isOpened: false, children: []}]}]; Then when you click on an item you can make ng-click="OpenItem(item);" Then function OpenItem(item) {item.isOpened = true;}

Comment: The array comes from a database. I would not want to touch it again ((

Comment: Just use that variable anyways then it will default to false.

Comment: Then the first time you opened it to me all the branches in the tree. And I need only in the context of a <ui>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a treeview is more adequate than multiples imbricated ng-repeat

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview